# Способ хранения и редактирование однотипных данных например об образовании

Tags: mysql, php, html, javascript

Необходимо сделать в профиле данные об образовании, но так как их может быть n количество хотел бы спросить каким способом лучше это реализовать. У меня несколько предположений:

1. сделать через массив и динамическую форму.
2. Создать отдельно таблицу где хранить данные в виде id user_id type value.

Может есть другие способы. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

На мое мнение, [сериализация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) вполне будет пригодна!

Comment: А вот такой вопрос в образовании есть несколько полей (дата обучения, место, высшее\среднее) это все редактируется в разных полях. В сериализации такое можно сделать?

Comment: @Hakster, сериализация преобразит любые данные в строку, так что ответ - да.

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму в чем проблема? Если мускул используете, то создаете отдельную табличку с полями

```
id, user_id, type, start_date, end_date, place, specialty
```

**UPD:**  Перечитал вопрос еще раз, но так и не понял, у вас сложности с фронтэндом или на бэкэнде?

Comment: и с тем и с другим первый раз столкнулся с динамическими формами и сохранениями их уже 2 день мучаюсь не могу вникнуть(